# Coroutine Kotlin Android with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
class Service{
    interface  RedditApi {
        @GET("/top.json")
        fun getTop(@Query("after") after: String,
                   @Query("limit") limit: String)
                : Deferred<Response<News>>;
    }
}
 val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val ongoing = chain.request().newBuilder()
                ongoing.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                ongoing.addHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"))
                //ongoing.addHeader("Authorization", val.trim());
                chain.proceed(ongoing.build())
            }
            .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl( "/rest/s1/mobile/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
        redditApi = retrofit.create(Service.RedditApi::class.java)
```

Okey I have that, am trying to use retrofit with Coroutine. I go to my activity and implement it like below.I get error dispatchers.main unresolved reference main.I am using kotlin 1.3.21. Also my other question is, what if user clicks back on the activity how can I cancel the coroutine operation?Like In Java I used to do call.cancel() with retrofit.It cancelled the call.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Fightable {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val request = App.redditApi.getTop("after", "limit")
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    try {
                        val response = request.await()
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val news: News? = response.body()
                            //Do something with response e.g show to the UI.
                        } else {
                        }
                    } catch (e: HttpException) {
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    }
                }
            }}}
```

Comment: `Dispatchers.Main` is not in the core coroutines library, but in `kotlinx-coroutines-android`.

Comment: yes thank you, i imported     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.2.0-alpha" for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a single instance of coroutine context and also have a job defined to it.

`val job = Job()
val coroutineScope = CoroutineContext(Dispatchers.Main+job)`

And start the work using the declared scope and when you want to cancel the work, you can simply call `job.cancel()` which cancels all current and upcoming works.

Comment: Hi, lets assume I called the url to server side. And then called cancel.Would the work on server side be cancelled too? Because thats what I want.

Comment: If guess if you cancel the ongoing request, the server would stop sending the data. Mostly it should. Try cancelling the retrofit request too.